Movie with an old mansion and a corridor of hands holding torches
This is a color film I saw somewhere before 1995. I would say it was in English and the production date was around the late 70's\80's.
The only scene I can remember in this film is when one of the characters was standing in a room on the first or second floor of an old mansion. He was looking out the window, when a female dressed in a white dress flies towards the window. He rushes to the window, but he just catches a glimpse of her as the lady walks away from the house on the garden's grass.
The part I vividly remember is that after this, he opens the door to go down the stairs and stepping out, he sees that the corridor's wall are decorated with seemingly motionless hands holding torches. As he goes forward, one of the hands that he has just passed by adjusts its grip of the torch, by firmly flicking the fingers through the handle of the torch.

Hi. Do you remember the approximate year? Was it in English? Was it in color?

it was color, that one is sure. i saw somewhere before 1995. i really can't tell if it was english or not, but i would say it was english. i would put the production date of the movie to somewhere late 70's, 80's

The only corridor like that that I can currently recall was in Jack the Giant Killer from 1962 (which was probably inspired by Cocteau's Beauty and the Beast, where the hands are holding candelabra instead of torches). The hands also hold swords later on and the hero fights his way through. But I don't think the rest fits.

now that you mention, maybe they were candelabras, not torches. so some kind of light-emitting stick...

Any chance it is High Spirits?

When Peter Plunkett's Irish castle turned hotel is about to be repossesed, he decides to spice up the attraction a bit for the 'Yanks' by having his staff pretend to haunt the castle. The trouble begins when a busload of American tourists arrive - along with some real ghosts. Among the tourists are married couple Jack and Sharon. Sharon's father holds the mortgage on Castle Plunkett, so she's hoping to debunk the ghosts. Jack, on the other hand, after meeting pretty ghost Mary, is very eager to believe. Can there be love between a human and ghost? Jack and Mary are going to try and find out.

The ghost Jack falls for wears a white dress.




I don't remember a corridor with hands holding torches, though. Was there a scene like that there?

saw only the trailer you have posted, but as I remember, the movie did not have this goofy vibe at all, it had a more serious tone and was really slow paced as I remember

the Farie Tale theatre version of Beauty and The Beast was very slow and kund of boring for what was supposed to be a childrens movie.it was a mid to late 80's release and in it Susan Serandon wears a white dress and walks down a corridor with hands holding torches.Hope this helps
